# jQuery cach a[href='"+w+"'] in IE - not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Problem is that IE dont find object with links in array? It is working in any other browser, but not in IE. I try everything. Any help, please.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="tminheight">
        <div class="content">
            <h2><a href="/folder/link1">link1</a></h2> <!-- links that need to be cached -->
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2><a href="/folder/link4">link4</a></h2> <!-- links that need to be cached -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/somewhere1">&nbsp;</a></li> <!-- links that need to be clicked -->
            <li><a href="/somewhere2">&nbsp;</a></li> <!-- links that need to be clicked -->
            <li><a href="/somewhere3">&nbsp;</a></li> <!-- links that need to be clicked -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Array with a links that need to be compared
    var lisNo = {0:'/folder/link1',1:'/folder/link2',2:'/folder/link3'};

    $.each(lisNo, function(q, w) {
    // Caching the links from array
        $("div.tminheight div.content h2 a[href$='"+w+"']").live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
            //Trigger a click on a link in list by ID from Array
            $('ul li:eq('+q+') a').trigger('click');
        return false;
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works, the trigger does not: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4vHL9/

Why not copy the href from the other link instead?

`$("someHiddenDiv").load( $('ul li:eq('+q+') a').attr("href"))`

Are your comments the wrong way around? You want to also click the links in the LI when you click the top links?

Comment: No comment are good.. 1. Take href from link, 2. Comper it to links from Array, 3. Than click on LI with index from maching element in Array

Answer (score 0):

Switch quotes:

```
$('div.tminheight div.content h2 a[href$="'+w+'"]').live('click', function(event) {
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference???? My fiddle worked with the quotes the other way too

Comment: @mplungjan dark magic ;) actually, firefox wants double quotes around attr substring selectors, too.

Comment: Did you try my fiddle? If what you said is correct, my fiddle would do NOTHING!

Comment: I vish to vote but i need some kind of 15 reputation points??